# How to integrate HTML form into django view and model?

Tags: html, django

I have one html file which contain submission form.

I want to use this HTML form in django with model and view.

I dont want to use form class in html like

```
<form method="post" action="">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

I want to use complete form code in HTML and use django model to store that data in database.

How can I do that?

Comment: you may access individual field through `{{ form.field_name }}`

Comment: I dont want to access fields but i want to use some jquery on that form.

Comment: use the above code as it is. It should generate related html code. Open ur favourite browser and do insepect the element. Find it's id and apply jquery func on that particular elem id.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for helping me out. :)

Comment: Why do you want to make your life harder? Yes you could just access the post data but what do you actually gain out of it? if you're using django, you should make the most of all that django has to offer

Comment: @Sayse I want to show preview of uploaded image and do some cropping operation on it before submitting. But I am not getting how to show preview. It is straight forward but m new in django so getting problem.

Comment: You should ask about that instead then, although that has nothing to do with the form submission, im sure there are plenty of javascript libraries around that show a preview.

Comment: @Sayse I found some javascript but for that form field id is necessary and i was not aware of that fact that id will generated by django automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the question that you want to use jQuery.Django by defaults generate id for its form element.

As avinash already said you can always inspect the element and get the id and classses but some time we need custom class in that case you can use something like.

If you want to write your own custom fields.

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModeName
        widgets = {
            'field_one': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'foo', 'name':'foo'})
            'field_two': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'bar', 'name':'bar'})
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @burning for helping me. I was not aware of that fact of django. Thanks a lot.